# One requirejs.config file for several projects

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to figure out how to make a good utility library using require.js. I am working on many small projects which are using many of the same modules/tools.

What bothers me is that every time I start a new project, I have to create a new require.config in my main file. Even if the shim and paths are the same for each project.

Is there a way to like include a default requirejs.config file to my main file in addition to the few settings each project needs? So it would look something like this (not sure if it is the right approach):

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "./",
    mainConfigFile: '../some/path/to/the/large/require.config.js'
    path: 'some/specific/paths/to/this/project'
});

require(['something'], function (Something) {

        new Something();

    }
);
```

Then '../some/path/to/the/large/require.config.js', contains settings I need in all my projects.

Hope this made sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue and here is my solution. First of all I created helper object in config.js:

```
;
(function(window) {
    window.require_config = window.require_config || {};
    var config = window.require_config.config = window.require_config.config || {};
    var cfg = {
        baseUrl: "",
        paths: {},
        shim: {}
    };

    config.addPath = function(key, path) {
        cfg.paths[key] = path;
        return this;
    };

    config.addShim = function(key, shim) {
        cfg.shim[key] = shim;
        return this;
    };

    config.setBaseUrl = function(baseUrl) {
        cfg.baseUrl = baseUrl;
        return this;
    };

    config.build = function() {
        return cfg;
    };
})(window);
```

Then I created common configuration (in my case I had only common base url):

```
;
(function (window) {
    var config = window.require_config.config;

    config.setBaseUrl('/Scripts');
})(window);
```

I also created separate configs for jQuery, jQuery UI and other libraries.

```
;
(function (window) {
    var config = window.require_config.config;

    // check for existing jQuery
    var jQuery = window.jQuery;

    // check for jQuery 
    if (!jQuery) {
        config.addPath("jquery", ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min', 'jquery-1.10.2.min']);
    } else {
        define('jquery', [], function () { return jQuery; });
    }
})(window);
```

It allows me easier to manage jQuery version changes. So I change version only in one place.

Next thing is to wire everything together on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/require.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    require(['/Scripts/Config/config.js'], function() {
        require(['/Scripts/Config/common-config.js',
                '/Scripts/Config/jquery-config.js',
                '/Scripts/Config/knockout-config.js',
                '/Scripts/Product/product-config.js'], function() {
                    require(['/Scripts/Product/main.js']);
                });
    });
</script>
```

First of all I include require.js itself, then require my helper script as it should be loaded first. Then I require all configuration scripts (library script configuration and my specific application configuration - product-config.js) and only after that I require my application script as it depends on all previous scripts.

And in application script (main.js in my example) first thing is to build and set configuration within require.js:

```
  var config = window.coop.config;
  require.config(config.build());
```